# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Future'

Tags: python

I am writing my first calculator code in python and classic programming error appears to send me on hiatus again :

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Future'
```

Below is the code: any idea what's happening?

```
input_1 = input(" what's the first no.")
input_2 = input(" what's the second no. ")
sum = int(input_1)
print(sum)
```

Comment: What are you entering for `input_1`?  And do you have any imported/created objects of class `Future`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the bug of Jupyter (you're doing your code there, right?).

In standard Interpreter there's no any error, your code is correct.

Comment: Its generally best to ask questions such as their IDE or programming environment in the comments as opposed to the answers section.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, next time I'll ask there)